# Dart redstone web application

Tags: web, dart, redstone.dart

Let's say I configure redstone as follows

```dart
    @app.Route("/raw/user/:id", methods: const [app.GET])
    getRawUser(int id) => json_about_user_id;
```

When I run the server and go to `/raw/user/10` I get raw json data in a form of a string.

Now I would like to be able to go to, say, `/user/10` and get a nice representation of this json I get from `/raw/user/10`.

Solutions that come to my mind are as follows:

1. First

   - create `web/user/user.html` and `web/user/user.dart`, configure the latter to run when `index.html` is accessed
   - in `user.dart` monitor query parameters (`user.dart?id=10`), make appropriate requests and present everything in `user.html`, i.e.

```dart
         var uri = Uri.parse( window.location.href );
         String id = uri.queryParameters['id'];
         new HttpRequest().getString(new Uri.http(SERVER,'/raw/user/${id}').toString() ).then( presentation )
```

A downside of this solution is that I do not achieve `/user/10`-like urls at all.

2. Another way is to additionally configure redstone as follows:

   ```dart
   @app.Route("/user/:id", methods: const [app.GET])
   getUser(int id) => app.redirect('/person/index.html?id=${id}');
   ```

in this case at least urls like "/user/10" are allowed, but this simply does not work.

How would I do that correctly? Example of a web app on redstone's git is, to my mind, cryptic and involved.

I am not sure whether this have to be explained with connection to redstone or dart only, but I cannot find anything related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are trying to generate html files in the server with a template engine. Redstone was designed to mainly build services, so it doesn't have a built-in template engine, but you can use any engine available on pub, such as [mustache](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mustache4dart). Although, if you use Polymer, AngularDart or other frameowrk which implements a client-side template system, you don't need to generate html files in the server.

Moreover, if you want to reuse other services, you can just call them directly, for example:

```dart
@app.Route("/raw/user/:id")
getRawUser(int id) => json_about_user_id;

@app.Route("/user/:id")
getUser(int id) {
  var json = getRawUser();
  ...
}
```

[Redstone v0.6](https://github.com/luizmineo/redstone.dart/tree/v0.6) (still in alpha) also includes a new foward() function, which you can use to dispatch a request internally, although, the response is received as a shelf.Response object, so you have to read it:

```dart
@app.Route("/user/:id")
getUser(int id) async {
  var resp = await chain.forward("/raw/user/$id");
  var json = await resp.readAsString();
  ...
}
```

**Edit:**

To serve static files, like html files and dart scripts which are executed in the browser, you can use the [shelf_static middleware](http://redstonedart.org/doc/Shelf-Middlewares.html). See [here](https://github.com/luizmineo/io_2014_contacts_demo) for a complete Redstone + Polymer example (shelf_static is configured in the [bin/server.dart file](https://github.com/luizmineo/io_2014_contacts_demo/blob/master/bin/server.dart#L52)).

Comment: Basically, my question boils down to the following. Once I have a redstone server responding with json on certain urls, how would I serve a web-page with a dart-script? That dart-script would run on a client requesting data from the server and rendering these data with Polymer or AngularDart. Is this possible with redstone at all?

Comment: I've edited the answer with information on how you can serve your client-side code.

Comment: Funny enough I found how to serve static files on redstonedart.org quite a while ago, but only now managed to make it work, i.e. made dart client scripts run. The mistake was quite silly: **Chromium cached empty scripts and html pages** and though I edited them and saw redstone serve them, they never ran. After I managed it to make it run, I wanted to say that on stackoverflow, but I was 3 mins later than your edit. Thanks.

Comment: To complete my comment I am gonna give a piece of code (specific to redstone) preventing caching dart-scripts:            `@app.Interceptor(r'/.*\.dart')
noCache(){
  app.chain.next((){
    app.response = app.response.change(headers:{            
              "Cache-Control" : "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
              "Pragma": "no-cache",
              "Expires": "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
          });
  });
}`   @luizmineo, It seems this piece would complete your answer.